# How to distribute N circles throughout the internal border of another circle via css/js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, math

I need to have a code that allows me insert any number os circles inside another circle, keeping the little ones evenly distributed.

The circles were created using `border-radius: 50%;`
There will be text inside the red circles. Yes, I know. It is complicated.

An expected organisation could be the following:

[image: circles inside circles]

Comment: Simple math - polar coordinates. The whole circle is 2 * pi, so angle between each circle should be 2 * pi / N

Comment: Can you add a little more context about what code you already have available? Even just code that defines how big the circles are and a function that draws the circles at given coordinates. At that point, the solution is simply figuring out the coordinates, which someone can provide as an answer.

Comment: But how to use polar coordinates with html elements? I'm thinking about using position: absolute, left: xxx, top: yyy for te red ones.

Comment: Absolute positioning and calculate top and left properties

Comment: I must say that the quantity of red circles with vary depending on the situation, so a need some that make the calculation of every red circle automatically, without assigning ids to them.

Comment: I maybe found an answer: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/04/quick-look-math-animations-javascript/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By some reason I can not insert snippet here, so http://jsfiddle.net/vr60dLth/

HTML

```
<div class='back'></div>
```

CSS

```
.back {
    background-color: green;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;
}

.front {
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: red;
}
```

jQuery

```
var N = 8, pi = Math.PI, backR = 100, frontR = 15, radius = 70;

$('.back').width(backR * 2).height(backR * 2);

for(var angle = 0; angle < 2 * pi; angle += 2 * pi / N)
{
    var s = $('<div class="front">').css({
         left: backR - frontR + radius * Math.cos(angle) + 'px',
         top:  backR - frontR + radius * Math.sin(angle) + 'px',
         width:  frontR * 2 + 'px',
         height: frontR * 2 + 'px'
    });
    $('.back').append(s);
}
```